# How to use correlated subquery into Active record query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, correlated-subquery

I am working on to get the customer details from different tables. I have created and tested this query and it's working fine. The Problem is how to the user (convert) this query into Active Records query. Thanks You.

```
            SELECT c.cust_id, `c`.`cust_contact_name`, `c`.`cust_active_flag`, 
            (select COUNT(`pm`.`cust_id`)  from property_master as pm 
            Where pm.cust_id = c.cust_id) as prop_count,
            (select a.addr_phoneno1 from address as a
            WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id AND a.addr_type_flag IN ('C', 'CP')) as cust_phone,
            (select count(ci.cust_id) from customer_inquiry as ci
            WHERE ci.cust_id = c.cust_id) as inquiry_count,
            (select max(inq_date) from customer_inquiry as ci
            WHERE ci.cust_id = c.cust_id) as last_inq_date
            FROM customer as c
            GROUP BY c.cust_ID
```

Comment: @hekmat  can you help on this sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter Active record classes don't have direct support for sub-queries. You can use any 3rd party library like [NTICompass CodeIgniter-Subqueries](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries) or `$this->db->query();` to execute your query.

Still, you can use the following way. But I will suggest to use `$this->db->query();`

```
$this->db->select('c.cust_id, `c`.`cust_contact_name`, `c`.`cust_active_flag`, 
            (select COUNT(`pm`.`cust_id`)  from property_master as pm ' Where pm.cust_id = c.cust_id) as prop_count, (select a.addr_phoneno1 from address as a
            WHERE a.cust_id = c.cust_id AND a.addr_type_flag IN ('C', 'CP')) as cust_phone,
            (select count(ci.cust_id) from customer_inquiry as ci
            WHERE ci.cust_id = c.cust_id) as inquiry_count,
            (select max(inq_date) from customer_inquiry as ci
            WHERE ci.cust_id = c.cust_id) as last_inq_date)
         ->from('customer c');
$this->db->group_by('c.cust_ID');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: thanks @Bikram But I am Looking for the other option than using query directly.

Comment: You can use any 3rd party CI library.

Comment: can you suggest anyone or direct link to look at.

Comment: I have updated the answer, with link to one library.